# OpenCV - Haartraining out of memory

Tags: windows, opencv

I have about 280 odd negative images and 7 positive images. When I tried to execute the haartraining.exe file over these files on 6gb and Quadcore processor machine. I get this error

[image]

The computer has 85% free memory. Below is the command that I am using. It uses about 55% of the memory and then dies. Any idea what is the mistake that I am doing.

`haartraining.exe -data data/cascade -vec data/vector.vec -bg negative/infofile.txt -npos 1800 -nneg 2620 -nstages 20 -mem 1000 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 -nonsym`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/53754), it looks like you can experiment with the `-mem` parameter that you pass into `haartraining.exe`. It looks like you currently have `-mem` set to `1000`. Can you try something like `-mem 3000`? Play around with the value of `-mem` and see what happens.

Comment: Hmmm... as a sanity check, can you try running haartraining.exe on a smaller set of images? See if that works, or if it fails even on a small set of images.

Answer (score -2):

-mem 1000 means 1000 Mb of RAM per stage. nstage by nmem should be less  than your  RAM capacity. In windows you can extend it.